# Why 'the' in front of a company name

Tags: definite-articles, proper-nouns

The sentence I have written is "IBM team uses CVS for storing the source code of the project". Should I add "The" in front of the the word "IBM". I am advised to do like that. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, we use 'The' for globally unique things or the things unique in specific context.

Answer (score 3):

Yes in that case you have to use **the**, because it doesn't refer to IBM but to the Team of IBM, because saying **The IBM Team** is the same as saying **the team of IBM**, and here **the article *the*** is used because we are talking about a specific team.

Because Referring to [***Using Articles*, Definite Article: "the" section**](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/540/01/) :

> The definite article is used before singular and plural nouns when the noun is specific or particular. The signals that the noun is definite, that it refers to a particular member of a group.

For example:

> "The dog that bit me ran away." Here, we're talking about a specific dog, the dog that bit me.
>
> "I was happy to see the policeman who saved my cat!" Here, we're talking about a particular policeman. Even if we don't know the policeman's name, it's still a particular policeman because it is the one who saved the cat.
>
> "I saw the elephant at the zoo." Here, we're talking about a specific noun. Probably there is only one elephant at the zoo.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we use 'The' for globally unique things or the things unique in specific context.